# Restore or replace an old NiCad battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, laptop, vintage, nicd-battery

I was finally able to buy a used Toshiba T4700CT to play my DOS games. I cleaned it, disassembled it and replaced both the backup battery and CMOS battery, but I have a question regarding the main battery.

It is a totally dead `12V NiCad` battery, I was wondering if I could replace it in some way, but I wasn't able to find a valid replacement.

I read that you can't replace it with a lithium battery as the charge process is not compatible.

Would you please suggest me what would you do in this case?

Comment: Leave charger on it? Get an external Pack?

Comment: iirc NiMH has very similar characteristics to NiCd.

Comment: Another way to go would be to find a ''battery guy'' that refurbish all kinds of battery. I'm lucky enough to get one in my area. He changed the cells of my laptop battery and my cordless drill battery. I, however, don't think that they are quite frequent hence the reason why I put it in the comment section.

Comment: Oh, and be sure to dispose of the old battery properly. Cadmium is a heavy metal and an environmental toxin, you really shouldn't just stick it in a landfill.